# Google App Engine - differences between the development server and the production server

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to ask what are the differences between the development server and the production server.
To be more specific, I give an example, I can run my application in the development server but when deploy to the production server, there is an error

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

So, can you please give me some advices?

```
08-20 03:50PM 46.168 / 500 34ms 61cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/3.0.195.6 Safari/532.0,gzip(gfe)

93.35.147.151 - - [20/Aug/2009:15:50:46 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/3.0.195.6 Safari/532.0,gzip(gfe)" "3-0.latest.foo.appspot.com"

E 08-20 03:50PM 46.199

<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named tools
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/base/data/home/apps/foo/3-0.335761381164787271/homepage.py", line 1, in <module>
    import models
  File "/base/data/home/apps/foo/3-0.335761381164787271/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
```

It is so strange that it gave me the message, "no module named tools", as I copied the code of [uploading data from google](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)
In the development server, it works :-s

Comment: Can you give more information? Specifically, are you running Python or Java on GAE? What is the full log entry for that error?

Comment: hi, I'm running Python on GAE.
Which log entry are you mentioning, I am sorry, I am just new to Python and GAE :-s

Comment: edited with output when uploading source to appspot

Comment: If you log into your GAE account and select the app you are having problems with, then go to Log on the left-hand side. Expand the error log for the URL you attempted to go to (or any URL if you are having problems with all URL's). This should give you a stacktrace for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors that occur in production are logged to the Admin Console. Log in to your admin console, select 'Logs', and look for the request that's causing the error. The stacktrace and all other relevant details will be there.